# Universal Objects in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

What is meant by Universal Objects in Sql Server?
Is it any objects which is available throughout every and any databases in the same server?

Comment: Where did you see this phrase? Not a standard/common term that I'm aware of. Maybe you should ask the author what they meant if it is not clear from the context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused with Universal Object Model / Universal Object Format - this is the idea that any object can be (technology independent) be represented in such a way that it can be compared across technologies.

For example, if you were to put it in context of a database you might want to see if your SQL Server User table is actually the same as an Oracle User table.

Theoretically, something would allow you to extract the definition of the table from two very different DBMS and test equality etc.

This isn't a SQL Server concept - heck it's not even a database concept per se. It's just a data / programming / IT concept. Interesting article [you might find relevant](http://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-00563-3_59).